# Running grunt "concurrent:test" Aborted due to warnings

Tags: angularjs, debian, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-concurrent

I'm using a **Yeoman angular generator** and when I run this code I get grunt exiting with a warning. I'm running inside debian wheezy and have run these commands before running grunt:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby           &&
sudo gem install sass compass       &&
npm install                         &&
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli       &&
sudo npm install -g bower           &&
```

gruntfile.js:

```
 grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

 test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
```

Warning:

```
Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task
    Warning:  Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-04-02 13:58:03 UTC)
concurrent:test  1.1s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 99%
Total 1.1s
Process finished with exit code 6
```

Comment: i had this error because of some wack scss syntax I'd written

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grunt exit code 6 is less than helpful, but the real point it is trying to tell you is that your tests had warnings (read: problems) in them and you should look at them. I would also suggest turning on JSHint or JSLint in your IDE and see what it comes up with. Running tests on a fresh install *should* work right out of the box, and having them failing is usually a sign of bad configuration, so check that too. Lastly, you might try re-installing Yeoman and making sure that every module installs without a problem.

Comment: I reinstalled yeoman and things are working better, was still  missing some karma plugins http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395388/1339087

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this as well.

After reading this thread I looked into my grunt file and found that concurrent:test was running compass.

I ran 'grunt compass' and saw a better error message.

Comment: This is what helped me - thx for posting.  I had pasted some invalid less code into my scss file and running grunt compass allowed me to find it and remove it.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you.